Can someone help me identify this mouse switch? Additionally is the discolloring on the board really bad?
This is for the Razor Naga Pro 1. Can someone help me find a replacement switch for this? It was two prong that went through the pictured holes. It is about 5 mm tall.
I had to tear it apart to get it off, and the soldering was really odd. It took like 899 degrees to actually melt the solder.



It is called "momentary tactile switch" and you can search for it at any electronic components store of your choice, making sure its size (leads distance) is right for your board.
You could also use the term "momentary tactile mouse switch" when searching.
If the temperature you're mentioning is in Fahrenheit, it's still a bit high.
It is likely that your soldering iron is not a very good one, or the tip maybe too small for the job.
The PCB may have more than two layers which could be drawing the heat away from the solder joints.

I wouldn't assume that consumer electronics were properly designed with thermal relief. They could be assuming that the board is only ever going through reflow soldering and not bother with a decent layout. If so the copper pour will act as heatsink.

@Lundin That's what I thought too, but I didn't mention it. Thank you for catching and correcting my typo.
